# Javascript : Merge All Array into one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays which I want to marge into one and remove duplicate values.

```js
let arr = [ {
  label :'XYZ',
  colors:['black','white','blue']
},
{
  label :'PQR',
  colors:['orange','yellow','white']
},

{
  label :'ABC',
  colors:['black','pink','blue']
},
]

let updatedArr = []


for(let i=0 i< arr.length ; i++ ){
  updatedArr.push(
                arr[i].reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], [])
            )

}
```

I want all the colors array value into one array and remove duplicate values as well.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To get a concatenated list of all values you can use [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).
And to deduplicate you can use `[...new Set(duplicates)]`, which creates a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of unique elements and spreads it into an array.

```js
let arr = [{
    label: 'XYZ',
    colors: ['black', 'white', 'blue']
  },
  {
    label: 'PQR',
    colors: ['orange', 'yellow', 'white']
  },

  {
    label: 'ABC',
    colors: ['black', 'pink', 'blue']
  },
]

let colors = [...new Set(arr.flatMap(obj => obj.colors))]
console.log(colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) for flatting the array, and then use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for distincting values and then create an array from the set using the [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator.

```js
let arr = [{
    label: 'XYZ',
    colors: ['black', 'white', 'blue']
  },
  {
    label: 'PQR',
    colors: ['orange', 'yellow', 'white']
  },

  {
    label: 'ABC',
    colors: ['black', 'pink', 'blue']
  },
]

const vals = [...new Set(arr.map(i => i.colors).flat())]

console.log(vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `forEach`. Inside reduce call back use `forEach` to iterate the `colors` array & if `accumulator` does not include the color then push that color to accumulator

```js
let arr = [{
    label: 'XYZ',
    colors: ['black', 'white', 'blue']
  },
  {
    label: 'PQR',
    colors: ['orange', 'yellow', 'white']
  },

  {
    label: 'ABC',
    colors: ['black', 'pink', 'blue']
  },
]


let mergedColor = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr.colors.forEach((item) => {
    if (acc.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      acc.push(item)
    }
  })

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(mergedColor)
```